# Laravel Sail on WSL2 - Wrong Permissions

Tags: php, laravel, docker, wsl-2

I'm trying to run Laravel Jetstream with Sail on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) and Docker.
So far I could use composer to install Laravel.

When I enter CLI mode to use "php artisan" commands this works fine.
As soon as I try to edit the files in Visual Studio Code with "code ."in the Project folder in the WSL2 Terminal, I got user and permission errors. User is set to "root" and file permissions to 644

Temporary fix is using:

```
sudo chown -R marek:marek *  
sudo chmod -R 655 *
```

in the WSL2 Terminal to set the user-owner and edit the permissions to be able to use Visual Studio Code on my files. I would need to do it every time on every new file or files created my the docker cli and php artisan commands.

I also tried to create wsl.conf in /etc with:

```
[automount]
enabled = true
options = "metadata"
mountFsTab = false
default=marek
```

Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Have you installed the remote WSL extensions? check out this 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Comment: How did you install the extension? Ware you using `root` to run `code .` or you run it as the user used by `php`?

Comment: I don't know how docker works in the wsl2 backend. I assume it's a docker issue as VS (and the extension) are working fine. Can do all the commands as I would be in a windows terminal. All the artisan commands happen in the Docker CLI.

Answer (score 0):

your wsl.conf is wrong, I guess. Try this:

```
[automount]
enabled = true
options = "metadata"
mountFsTab = false

[user]
default=marek
```